# Get currently selected data point from axes in a figure

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a MATLAB figure with an axes containing a scatter plot.
Every point on this scatter plot has a  signal data array associated with it.
I want to take user input as point selection from scatter plot and plot the corresponding signal data in another axes on the same figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine a global definition of your second axes with an UpdateFcn on the datacursor. See example below, which generates a sine wave based on a random variable selected.

```
function getSelectedDataPoint()
% create figure
fig = figure;
% make second axes a global to adress in myupdatefcn
global ax2
% define axes
ax1 = axes('parent',fig,'position',[0.05 0.05 0.9 0.4]);
ax2 = axes('parent',fig,'position',[0.05 0.55 0.9 0.4]);
% Random scatter
scatter(ax1,rand(25,1),rand(25,1),25,'filled')
% Set datacursormode to on
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
datacursormode on
% Specify objective function for clock
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)

% Define objective function
function text = myupdatefcn(~,obj)
text = sprintf('X: %f \n Y: %f',[obj.Position(1),obj.Position(2)]);
% Find corresponding signal
id = find(and(obj.Position(1) == obj.Target.XData,obj.Position(2) ==             
obj.Target.YData));
% Do your thing with the signals
x = 0:0.1:100;
y = sin(obj.Target.XData(id)*x);
% plot on second axes
plot(ax2,x,y)
end
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it was quite helpful. but I see that you have found the id of the point based on its coordinates. In my case I need to plot the points through a loop, and hence the obj.Target needed for assigning the id keeps changing, thereby resulting in the separate points giving the same id. I understand plotting all the points in one go would eliminate this issue, but are you aware of any other way. Or is there any way to add points without adding more objects. Sorry for unclear question and comment... hope you can tell me the way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I entirely understand what you want to do, but you might want to use the "Tag" option available for many objects in MATLAB.

Replace line under "Random scatter" by:

```
% Random scatter
hold(ax1,'on')
scatTag = cell(1,10);
for i = 1:10
scatTag{i} = scatter(ax1,rand(1,1),rand(1,1),25,'filled');
scatTag{i}.Tag = num2str(i);
end
```

In the data cursor update function, replace the line "id= find(..."

```
tagname = obj.Target.Tag;
```

And modify the signal function to point to your target tag, whatever function that is. In my example, you could do this to define the y-values:

```
y = sin(str2double(tagname)*x);
```

It will generate another sine wave, based on the tag.

Hope this helps :)